# M365 Oultook running on a terminal server dosn't show js add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin

There is a terminal server where users log on and use Outlook with their mailbox. There are users who see the ribbon button of our javascript add-in and can run it and there are users who doesn't see the ribbon button. It is M365 Outlook. In OWA, the add-in is visible for all the mailboxes. The group policy settings is the same for all the mailboxes.
Do you have any idea what can cause the add-ins visibility issue for some mailboxes in M365 Outlook on a terminal server?

(M365 mailboxes using Microsoft® Outlook® für Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 32 Bit)